# ASP.NET Core WebApi not picking up application pool user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Seems like I missing something basic here. I deployed a **ASP.NET Core WebApi** application to IIS. It's working fine. But have issues connecting to database.

I am using **integrated security = true** in my ConnectionString. I expect it to load the **identity from ApplicationPool** and use that to connect with DB. But it's not loading the identity. The error is that **login failed for user ''**

Wondering if .NET Core works differently.

**Update**

I found that "Enabling Windows Authentication" conflicts with app pool identity. As soon as I disabled windows authentication on the API and allow anonymus access. It started working fine.

Now the issue I have is that, how do I make both work together.

Regards,

Gaurav Sharma

Comment: Access to your App (WebAPI) (windows/annonymous) is not necessarily related to how the app access the DataBase. You say it is "working Fine" but it sounds like it isn't if it's not connecting to the Database. Depending on your configuration Your DB server is probably not allowing "integarated security" i.e. it does not recognize the machine that is trying to access it  what is the error/exception saying?

Comment: HI Danidev, the exception just says that the user doesn't have access to the database. The user its using to connect is the one logged on the website (incase windows authentication is enabled).

Comment: I would recommend that you great a SQL login to your database and use that in your  database connection string. Don't forget to change from Integrated Security = true to "Persist Security Info=True"